# Calculate last index of loop for each thread in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

If I have the following loop

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( i=0; i<10; i++ ){
    // for each thread, what will be the last index?
}
```

How do I calculate the last index of each thread without explicitly specifying the number of threads to use.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you do not do that. The OpenMP will dynamically 
distribute chunks of the loops across threads, so depending of the number 
of threads used, it would differ.

But also, you do not have the guarantee that each thread will execute 
just one chunk, it is possible (depending on the default schedule strategy
used) that the loop will be divided in more chunks then threads, and then 
each threads will execute several chunks.

If you want to control this, you could parallelize the for loop by yourself.  First, create parallel  region without the "for" keyword, 
calculate the start and end indices for each thread depending on its id, and then perform the loop.